# Why is the exponential function used function used when solving linear 2nd order homogeneous differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my textbook the introduction to solving linear 2nd order homogeneous DE's begins with a general form:

$ay''+by'+ cy =0$

Then they say: "a solution must have the property that its second derivative is expressible as a linear combination of its first and zeroth derivatives. This suggests a solution of the form:"

$y=e^{rt}$

By this doesn't seem intuitive to me. How is the second derivative of the exponential function expressible as a linear combination of its first and zeroth derivative? Would that not mean the following:

$r^2e^{rt}=re^{rt}+e^{rt}$

Which isn't true. So what could they mean by that?

Comment: Try using other coefficients. You’ve written a *specific* linear combination.

Comment: Look up the definition of "linear combination"! It's not the same as "sum"..

Answer (score 3):

The point is that if you plug $y=e^{rt}$ into the equation you get $ar^2e^{rt}+bre^{rt}+ce^{rt}=0$.  Since we know that $e^{rt}$ is never zero we can divide it out, getting $ar^2+br+c=0$.  We can solve this for two values of $r$.  For each of these values, the original equation will be satisfied.  Call the two roots $r_1, r_2$.  As any multiple of a solution is also a solution and the sum of two solutions is also a solution (you should verify this) any function of the form $Ae^{r_1t}+Be^{r_2t}$ will satisfy the equation.  When you wrote your last equation you lost $a,b,c$.  When you put them in properly you will get the analysis I presented.

Comment: "any function of the form Aer1t+Ber2t will satisfy the equation."

But they aren't the only solutions to the diff. equation right ?
Then why does my textbook give a fomula for general solution as this ?

Comment: is the exponential function the only solution to ay′′+by′+cy=0 ?

Comment: Yes.  We have demonstrated it provides two solutions.  There is a theorem I don't remember that says the solution is unique given initial conditions, so this is all.  The theorem requires that the function be Lipschitz, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

"a solution must have the property that its second derivative is expressible as a linear combination of its first and zeroth derivatives."

"So what could they mean by that?"

If

$ay^{\prime\prime}+by^\prime+cy=0$

then

$y^{\prime\prime}=-\frac{b}{a}y^\prime-\frac{c}{a}y$

That is all that is meant by that statement.